# ifstream opens files named by cin but not when pulled from an array. Any difference between cin and a regular string definition?

Tags: c++, arrays, file, ifstream, cin

TL;DR File names stored as strings in array (using new) - ifstream won't open them (perror returns "No such file or directory"). Swap out array variable with a call to the user to name the file (using cin) - ifstream opens the file. Why? How do I get the array to work?

**Things to Know**

- All files exist in folders with naming scheme run20### where
- All files are named S20###.ABC where ### is the same from the parent directory and ABC can go from 001-999. These are all text files (there are no .txt extensions though) that CAN be opened by ifstream and getline.

I'm writing a program that's going to pull information from up to 150 files. An early version I wrote had the user input the file name (using cin). ifstream took the stored name and opened the file successfully every time. Obviously, I don't want to type 150 file names in so the program stores all of the file names as strings in an array for the program to pull from. However, when it goes to open the file (in the correct path and with the correct file name and extension), the error I get from perror returns "No such file or directory." If I just do a quick swap of the variables though so that the file name comes from cin, the file opens. Why would cin work and the array version not? Is there any way to get the array to work?

I've also tried something similar where there is no array. Instead, in the for loop that would pull the files from the array, the file gets named each time.

Here's the code (sorry about the headers, couldn't get it to format right):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
//--------------------------Initial setup----------------------------------
    cout << "Please give the full name of the folder you would like to open in the /Users/lucas/HPS/TDCData directory" << endl << endl;
    string sFolderName;
    cin >> sFolderName;

    // Create path. I have mine here but you'll have to change it to something you'll 
    // use if you want to run the code
    string sPathName = "/Users/lucas/HPS/TDCData/" + sFolderName;

//----------------Create file name array------------------------------------    
    // Get naming base from the folder name given
    string sFileBase = "S20";
    for (int i = 5; i <= sFolderName.length(); i++){
            sFileBase = sFileBase + sFolderName[i];
    }

    //Specify range since different directories have different numbers of files
    cout << "Files must be named S20###.ABC" << endl;
    cout << "Specify a range for ABC" << endl;
    int iFloor;
    int iCeiling;
    cout << "Floor: " << endl;
    cin >> iFloor;
    cout << "Ceiling: " << endl;
    cin >> iCeiling;

    // Define an array to store names and then store them
    string *aFiles;
    int iFilesSize = iCeiling - iFloor + 1;
    aFiles = new string [iFilesSize];
    cout << "Array created" << endl;
    for (int i = iFloor; i <= iCeiling; i++){
        string name = sFileBase;
        if (i < 10){
            name = name + ".00" + to_string(i);
        }
        else if (i < 100) {
            name = name + ".0" + to_string(i);
        }
        else {
            name = name + '.' + to_string(i);
        }
        aFiles[i-1] = name;
    }

//----------------Open each file in aFiles----------------------
    for (int i = 0; i < iFilesSize; i++){
        // There are two important lines of code here. The first gets sFileName from
        // aFiles. The second gets sFileName from user input using cin (this is commented out). 
        // Obviously, none of the last section of code is needed for the second line to work.
        // The first line does not work for me. The second does.

        string sFileName;

        //First
        sFileName = aFiles[i];

        //Second
        //cin >> sFileName

        string sFullPath = sPathName + "/" + sFileName;
        cout << "Searching ... " << sFullPath << endl << endl;

        //Open file
        ifstream inputFile(sFullPath);

        //Check that the file opened
        if (! inputFile.is_open()) {
        cout << "Error reading" << sFullPath << endl;
            perror("Error is: ");
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            cout << "File opened successfully..." << aFiles[i] << endl << endl;
        }
    }
    cout << "All files opened..." << endl << endl;
    return 0;

}
```

Also [here's](http://1drv.ms/1cjR1Ui) a link to a zip of one of the directories for any tests someone might want to run. Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: Your approach looks much to complicated for my taste. I'd simply use a [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) to generate the file names using the `operator<<()` functions (giving a separate line for each file path), and reading from that one afterwards, instead of using `std::cin`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you start filling `aFiles` from index `iFloor`, while you start reading `aFiles` from index `0`.

How about changing `aFiles[i-1] = name;` to `aFiles[i-iFloor] = name;`

Comment: Thanks. I actually noticed that just after posting. `iFloor` always starts at 1 though so no issue has actually arisen from that.

Answer (score 0):

> *"TL;DR File names stored as strings in array (using new)"*

Don't do this. Use a dynamic container like `std::vector<std::string>` instead.

> *"- ifstream won't open them (perror returns "No such file or directory")."*

Use the debugger to check what's actually passed to the

```
ifstream inputFile(sFullPath);
```

with `sFullPath`.

> *"Swap out array variable with a call to the user to name the file (using cin) - ifstream opens the file. Why? How do I get the array to work?"*

You cannot *replace* the behaviors of a stream getting values as you're trying with the array.

The best way to make the input stream source transparent, is to simply use a `std::istream` reference, and don't care if it's `std::cin` or e.g. a `std::istringstream` reference.

The `std::string` instance needed to initialize the mentioned `std::istringstream` can be build e.g. using a `std::ostringstream` and pass the `str()` property to the `std::istringstream` constructor.